# Расхождение с дизайном фоновых элементов в реальной работе это нормально?

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я как человек скурпулезный, внимательно отношусь к деталям. В реальной работе верстальщика такие различия с макетом это допустимо? Тут можно увидеть что верхние левые облака не совсем по макету
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё зависит от многих факторов и точного ответа вы тут не получите.

Comment: Ну там не только облака, там ещё блок "Track your next fuel shops" стоит левее. Но тут надо учесть на каком разрешении монитора вы смотрите. Уверен на компьютере и на ноутбуке будет по разному выглядеть.

Comment: Текст "Monitor adn Alert" также под наклоном, а в шаблоне без наклона и это можно считать недочётом, а облачка - этот фактор состоит из множества возможных причин, первая причина описана выше.

Comment: Не видя самой страницы вам никто не скажет точно, виноват в этом заказчик или исполнитель

Comment: Мужик, нет ничего идеального